# is there to retrieve the synatx of pl sql body using sql query?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

i have access to database , and i want to retrieve pl sql body through sql
let it the body be :

```
procedure A ( P_INPUT1 out varchar)
is 
begin
select sysdate into P_INPUT1  from dual;
end;
```

I want to write a sql query to get the syntax of that body 
how to achieve that ?

Answer (score 2):

You get sources from `USER_SOURCE`, `ALL_SOURCE` or `DBA_SOURCE`. Docs: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/statviews_2063.htm#i1588578

```
select text
from user_source
where name = 'A' and type = 'PROCEDURE'
order by line;
```

Answer (score 1):

dbms_metadata.get_ddl   - see https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_metada.htm#BGBBIEGA